# Creating a Custom Pie Style Circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to cut a slice out of a circle but it is proving to be harder than I originally anticipated...

Preferably, I do not want to use Google Charts and any other equivalents as I need to have as much control on the style of this circle as possible (the end result is a loading ring). I will also need to be able to animate, either using jQuery or CSS, the size of the slice.

Please forgive me but I haven't got very far, this is all I have:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0yu95u3/1/)

The circles I am concerned about are `#layer_2` and `#layer_3`. Here is the code for just this circle:

```css
#layer_2 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 212px;
  height: 212px;
  margin: 14px;
  background: #5c00d2;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #5c00d2 0%, #d586f4 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, #5c00d2), color-stop(100%, #d586f4));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #5c00d2 0%, #d586f4 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #5c00d2 0%, #d586f4 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, #5c00d2 0%, #d586f4 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #5c00d2 0%, #d586f4 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5c00d2', endColorstr='#d586f4', GradientType=1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 3px rgba(5, 71, 110, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 3px rgba(5, 71, 110, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 3px rgba(5, 71, 110, 0.5);
}
#layer_3 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 212px;
  height: 212px;
  margin: 0;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id="layer_2">
  <div id="layer_3"></div>
</div>
```

I would like the end result to look similar to this:

[image: Loading Ring]

Comment: This will be very very difficult to do without using canvas or svg elements.

Comment: @Shomz I thought that might be the case :-(. Canvas and SVG's are the one thing I do not have experience with. Is it hard?

Comment: @Shomz I tend to agree, you can't really do this in CSS. I think using canvas is going to be faster.

Comment: @BenCarey; No it isn't hard. This is pretty basic stuff. I'm no expert on them and with the help of some tuts on the internet I was able to code a hexagon grid and pie charts.

Comment: Well, they will take some time to learn, but not hard. However, you can try to keep as many things you already have - for example, the whole circle can be set as an element behind the canvas/svg, and then you can just "cut out" the slice by placing the triangularish shape on top of it.

Comment: @Shomz Can I animate using canvas/svg?

Comment: Absolutely! You can animate up to the slightest detail with canvas, and you can use CSS transitions/transformations and value animations for SVGs.

Comment: @Shomz Awesome! Thanks so much guys, this is really helpful. Unfortunately I am in an extreme rush to get this done as soon as possible so I will have to focus on getting the rest of the site built before I tackle this. Thank you so much, both of you :-)

Comment: No problem, good luck with it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> ## layer_2

```
background-image:
    linear-gradient(-90deg, transparent 50%, #5c00d2 50%),
    linear-gradient(200deg, #5c00d2 50%, transparent 50%);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/w0yu95u3/4/)

Comment: This is great but unfortunately I cannot get it to work with gradients :-( +1 for effort